# ReactNative - Get data from API into List View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

First attempt at pulling data from an API into react native, I think im pretty close but I am getting "Cannot read property 'DataSource' of undefined".

https://gist.github.com/ElliotReeve/a15ef765dab8267fd952b6483c0b4a32

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess... but I think you're mixing up RN ListView with native-base. You're setting it up like RN's ListView but then using NB. I don't think you need to set a DataSource if you're using NB and just pass a normal array into ListView as `dataArray` and they will handle all that for you.

```
this.state = {
  appointments: []
}
...
<ListView dataArray={this.state.appointments}>
```

Comment: Also, I believe your `ListItem`s should be in your `renderRow` function

Comment: I have updated the gist with the latest - now getting "Element type is invalid: expected string (for built in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined"

Comment: Try deleting all those listitems (those need to be in renderRow) and you still need renderRow next to your dataArray which will define what each row will look like. But that error shows up when you have an element that is either misspelled/not imported correctly or doesn't exist

Comment: you also deleted your constructor so this.state.appointments is no longer defined.

Comment: Updated the gist - if i remove the new "<ListView data...." section the error goes away...but i cant get it to work with it in place.

Comment: ohh just figured it out, in nativebase its just `List` not `ListView`. dont forget to change that in the import statement too, and I guess you could put those ListItems back if you arent planning them to be part of this list

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured it out at the same time, its working now :) Thanks for the help!